# Pushing to git (senior dev)

Tags: git, github

When you push to a git rep, should you'r code always work? Or can you upload some code with a few errors for some co-workers/friends to review.

A senior dev, just told me that when ever you push to a git the code should always work and never have errors. But how are others suppose to review the code, if you have a problem?  The senior said that it is a rule on Git... is it?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/

Comment: It should depend on your team processes

Answer (score 6):

This is why people use feature/personal branches. You can push a branch with your changes in it for others to review, then merge into master after review. That's the standard pattern for git.

1. Make feature branch
2. Do work
3. Commit/push to branch
4. Send pull request
5. Others review and approve pull request
6. Changes are merged into master

Or something along those lines...

Comment: Agree..  developers should be free to push / rebase  do whatever they please to their branches until (4) happens.   At that point a nice CI server should run the tests and other checks to and let others know that changes are ready for review.

Comment: The CI server can also test feature branches before the pull request. It's good to know early if your code is screwed up in ways you didn't realize, and it means the integrator doesn't have to sit around waiting for tests to finish.